# Multinomial logistic regression in R returns fewer categories

Tags: r, regression, logistic, categorical-data, nnet

My dependent variable has 4 categories, but when I run the multinomial logistic regression using the package `nnet` with function `multinom` the results only show 3 categories.

I've tried changing the category numbers from 0,2,3,4 to 1,2,3,4, and also tried using names instead of numbers for the categories but it still wont show all 4 categories in the results.

Also, when I changed the categories to names instead of numbers, the resulting p values for each category drastically changed. Why is this? 
The p values were acquired using these commands

```
z <- summary(siglm)$coefficients/summary(siglm)$standard.errors
p <- (1 - pnorm(abs(z), 0, 1)) * 2
p
```

Comment: The missing category is the reference category. All the coefficients are interpreted with reference to that category.

Comment: Ah, OK, thank you! How do I get the p-value for that reference category?

Answer (score 2):

The missing category is the reference category. All the coefficients are interpreted with reference to that category.

You can change the reference category and run the same model to get statistics related to the reference category. By default the first factor level is the reference category.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, how do I change the reference category? Do I just change its number? Also if the reference category is changed, wouldnt that result in the p-values of the others being different, since they are related to a different category?

Comment: in `R`, you can look it up for the proper syntax by doing `factor`

Comment: Thanks, is there a website that explains how to do this and how this works? Im a R beginner and this is very confusing for me :)

Comment: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/mlogit.htm

Comment: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Changing_the_order_of_levels_of_a_factor/

Comment: Ah the second link answers my question very well! Thank you very much, you were very helpful! :D